# JAVA,MySQL - How to ArrayList return and call

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

I am JAVA beginner. How to return ArrayList values and call other class?
I don't know what to do....
This is my code.

```
public ArrayList<String> deleteList(String filename){

       Connection conn = null;
       Statement stmt = null;
       int i=0;
       ArrayList<String> d_list = new ArrayList<String>();

       try{
          conn = getConnection();

          System.out.println("Creating statement...");
          stmt = conn.createStatement();

          String sql;
          sql = "select f_name,access_time,"
                + "(select count(*) + 1 from c_DB where access_time>c.access_time) as rank "
                + "from c_db as c having rank >= 8 order by rank";

          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

          while(rs.next()){

             String A = rs.getString("f_Name");
             d_list.add(i,A);
             i++;
          }
          /*for(int j=0;j<d_list.size();j++){
              System.out.print("\n" +d_list.get(j));
          } */        
          rs.close();
          stmt.close();
          conn.close();
       }catch(SQLException se){
          se.printStackTrace();
       }catch(Exception e){     
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
       System.out.println("\nDeletelist");         
    return d_list;            
}
```

I want to return d_list and use.

```
public class CacheManager {
    public void DeleteCache(){

        ArrayList<String> d_name= new ArrayList<String>();
        DBManager name =new DBManager();
        for(int i=0;i<d_name.size();i++){
            d_name.addAll(i,name.deleteList(d_list));
        }
        for(int j=0;j<d_name.size();j++){
              System.out.print("\n" +d_name.get(j));
          }

    }
    public void SendList(){             
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CacheManager c = new CacheManager();
        c.DeleteCache();
    }
}
```

But Always error create method!!..
I don't know how to fix DeletCache() part.
Plase help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in how you add to your List in your while loop and other places.

it should be as

```
      while(rs.next()){
         String A = rs.getString("f_Name");
         d_list.add(A);
      }
```

You dont need the counter.

Comment: It isn't good code style to name a variable in capital letter. So you better use `String a`